# How to split string and store in list via TCL

Tags: tcl

Is there a way to  split strings and save in a list ?
How to split string and save in two list
For example, I have a string where I split several string with `=`:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
```

and then I want to create two list like this `[a,b,c,d]` and `[1,2,3,4]`:

Comment: *a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4* is a single string?

Comment: yes but there are no comma in between and they all are in new line for example a=1 in new line b=2 and so on

Answer (score 10):

Following is a simple tcl code

```
set s "a=1\nb=2\nc=3\nd=4"
set s [split $s "\n"]
foreach e $s {
    set e [split $e "="]
    lappend l1 [lindex $e 0]
    lappend l2 [lindex $e 1]
}
```

Now you have list l1 with [a b c d] and l2 has [1 2 3 4]

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to read all the data in, `split` into lines, and then use `regexp` with each line to extract the pieces.

```
set f [open "theFile.txt"]
set lines [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set keys [set values {}]
foreach line $lines {
    if {[regexp {^([^=]*)=(.*)$} $line -> key value]} {
        lappend keys $key
        lappend values $value
    } else {
        # No '=' in the line!!!
    }
}

# keys in $keys, values in $values

puts "keys = \[[join $keys ,]\]"
puts "values = \[[join $values ,]\]"
```

Run that (assuming that the filename is right) and you'll get output like:

```
keys = [a,b,c,d]
values = [1,2,3,4]
```

---

Collecting two lists like that might not be the best thing to do with such stuff. Often, it is better to instead to store in an array:

```
# Guarded by that [regexp] inside the foreach
set myArray($key) $value
```

Like that, you can do lookups by name rather than having to manually search. Assuming that keys are unique and order doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 for arrays. use [`parray`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/library.htm) to inspect it.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way might be using a loop:

```
% set lines "a=1\nb=2\nc=3\nd=4"
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
% set expressionList [split $lines "\n"]
a=1 b=2 c=3 d=4
% set var [list]
% set val [list]
% foreach i $expressionList {
    set variable [lindex [split $i "="] 0]
    set value [lindex [split $i "="] 1]
    lappend val $value
    lappend var $variable
}
% puts $var
a b c d
% puts $val
1 2 3 4
```

If you don't mind a regex, you might try something like this:

```
% set lines "a=1\nb=2\nc=3\nd=4"
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
% set var [regexp -inline -lineanchor -all -- {^[^=\n\r]+} $lines]
a b c d
% set val [regexp -inline -lineanchor -all -- {[^=\n\r]+$} $lines]
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

If replacing the equals sign characters in `$data` with blanks always leaves a proper, even-valued list (as in the example) it can be done a lot simpler:

```
set dict [string map {= { }} $data]
set keys [dict keys $dict]
set values [dict values $dict]
```

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Let say your strings placed in file abc.txt in the following order

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4
```

You need to create 2 lists, one for numbers and one for characters:

```
set number_list [list]
set char_list   [list]

set fh [open "abc.txt" "r"]

while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
    regexp -- {(\S+)=(\S+)} $line foo char number
    lappend char_list   $char
    lappend number_list $number
}

close $fh

puts $char_list
puts $number_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but I would actually go about it differently... Something like the following, considering that the string is [a=1\nb=1\n ... etc.] with variable name "str":

```
# determine num entries in string
set max [llength $str]

#create new strings (alph & num) based on split string
set i 0
set str [split $str \n]
set alph []
set num []
while {$i < $max} {
    set alph "$alph [lindex [split [lindex $str $i] "="] 0]
    set num "$num [lindex [split [lindex $str $i] "="] 1]
incr i}
```

Maybe just personal preference, but seems simplest to me; code was not tested, but it's similar to something I was just working on.