# Split with two-character delimiter

Tags: tcl

In tcl (version 8.4), I want to split a string like this:

```
"param1=>someval param2=>anotherval"
```

Into two lists, e.g.:

```
params = param1 param2
values = someval anotherval
```

If it were a single delimiter, e.g. `=`, I could use the `split` command.  Is there an equivalent for a double-character delimiter?

Comment: This question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627906/how-to-split-string-and-store-in-list-via-tcl/25367280#25367280

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps use [`regexp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm) to get the parameter/value pairs, like for example:

```
set text "param1=>someval param2=>anotherval"
set params [list]
set values [list]

foreach {all param value} [regexp -all -inline -- {(\S+)=>(\S+)} $text] {
    lappend params $param
    lappend values $value
}

puts $params
puts $values
# => param1 param2
# => someval anotherval
```

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/p06zN9tY)

The regexp `(\S+)` captures a sequence of non-space characters (including non-newlines and similar characters) so that if your parameters and values contain spaces, you will have to revise the pattern (see the [re syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)). If there are no spaces within them, then the above should work without any issues.

---

If you want to split twice, i.e. once on the space and then on the `=>`, then I would suggest using a [`string map`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm#M34) in there:

```
set text "param1=>someval param2=>anotherval"
set list [split $text]

set params [list]
set values [list]

foreach elem $list {
    set newElem [string map {=> \0} $elem]
    set pair [split $newElem \0]
    lappend params [lindex $pair 0]
    lappend values [lindex $pair 1]
}

puts $params
puts $values
# => param1 param2
# => someval anotherval
```

Here, we are substituting the characters to be split on `=>` by null `\0` (which is a character unlikely to appear in normal strings) and then split on null.

Comment: Actually, a `string map` might be better; you've got a literal string to replace, not a complex pattern.

Comment: Agreed. Too much regexp going on :s

Comment: I think the regexp is quite elegant, since it rejects malformed input without further special handling.

Answer (score 2):

Jerry's way is great. This can be achieved with the usage of `scan` also.

```
set input "param1=>someval param2=>anotherval"

foreach element $input { 
    if {  [ scan $element {%[^=>]=>%s} p v ] == 2 } { 
        puts $p
        puts $v
    } else { 
        puts "Scan failed for param and value. :("
    }
}
```

Here, I am taking advantage of Tcl's list implementation, since it is acting as a list which is separated with a space. If the input is not having a space, then the `scan` command has to be customized.

Comment: I like this because it attempts to deal with errors

Answer (score 1):

Try the textutil package from tcllib:

http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil.html

It has a procedure called `::textutil::splitx` which does what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't specify no external libraries in the question, but it's simple enough that I'd prefer not to add a dependency just for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do this:

```
set text "param1=>someval param2=>anotherval"

foreach {p v} [string map {=> { }} $text] {
    lappend params $p
    lappend values $v
}

set params
# => param1 param2
set values
# => someval anotherval
```

By replacing the `=>` substrings with spaces, you get an even-sized list where every other element is a parameter name string and every other a value string. This is assuming there isn't any white space inside the parameter names or values.

Documentation: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Comment: Elegant, but doesn't cope well with malformed input, hence Dinesh's answer is more robust.