# TCL: How the regex for every line should look like?

Tags: regex, tcl

In TCL, in output I have something like this:

```
ABBAA 1 BAABA 1 DNS3 0 0 200 300 400 500 0 0
ABBAA 1 BAABA 1 DNS1 0 0 200 300 400 500 0 0
ABBAA 1 BAABA 1 DNS7 0 0 200 300 400 500 0 0
ABBAB 1 BAABB 1 DNS5 0 0 200 300 400 500 0 0
ABBAB 1 BAABB 1 DNS3 0 0 200 300 400 500 0 0
```

I would like to sort this table alike dataset by fourth column ascending (so the first one will be row with DNS1UP1, then DNS2UP2 etc.) I figured out that regexp will be easiest method by looking for string with "DNS.." in it. But my method doesn't work exacly how I thought, because it is matching only one line or no line at all.

My method:

```
regexp "ABB.*DNS1.*?\N" 
ABB - match beginning of new line
.* - every character between ABB and DNS..
DNS1 - match the main looking for word
.* - every character between DNS... and new line symbol
?\n - non-greedy occurence of new line
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe your `.*` is too greedy, can you try `.*?` ?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are running? It's really not clear what you are doing...

Comment: In any case, maybe you need to `-line` option to `regexp`, documented here: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm

Comment: You can also just used `split` to split your input in lines, if that's all your trying to do. See the call to `split` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19628641/3216427

Comment: Is that dataset a list of strings? And I'm not sure why you are using regexp if you are trying to sort. Have you tried using [`lsort`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of lines in such a regular format, you can just `lsort` them… with the right options. In particular, `-dictionary` is good for mixed text/numbers and `-index 4` lets you choose the column to sort by.

```
set sortedLines [lsort -index 4 -dictionary $unsortedLines]
```

The only possible reasonable use of `regexp` in this would have been in preparing the data for the sort, but that string which you provided is already sortable (assuming you've done a `split $data "\n"` on it to actually convert it into a *list* of lines and are not just using a big ol' string).